# How to pass UserId Dynamically when reading the event information related to user and How to pass userid to RestRequest?

Tags: apex, soql, api, query, apexrest

I want to get the user related events based on userid I'm trying to retrieve the event details. Here my query is:

```
List<Event> events = [SELECT Subject,StartDateTime,EndDateTime FROM Event WHERE OwnerId =:userinfo.getUserId()];
```

I'm trying to expose through REST API. How can I pass the UserId to RestRequest like here

```
String OwnerId =req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

but how to link those two? For checking I'm using workbench by passing the user id I'm getting the event details related to that user but it won't display anything.

Comment: Are you just trying to set up a REST endpoint that will find the `Event` records owned by a specified user?

Comment: yes,that's the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your query to use the string you parsed out.

```
String ownerId = req.requestURI.substringAfterLast('/');
List<Event> events = [SELECT ... FROM Event WHERE OwnerId = :ownerId];
```

Then you would need to make sure you hit an endpoint that does indeed terminate with `/<some_user_id>`.

Comment: Thank you so much Adrian it works properly but it returns only one event details how to retrieve all events related to that particular userid

Comment: Are you sure there is more than one `Event` for the specified `User`? Are you sure the `User` you're running the query as can access those records?

Comment: yes just now i created two events for a user based on that user id i'm getting only one event how to overcome this.i want to retrieve all.